# Do I need to have Global Admin right to register an Application for Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

In Adam Saxton's youtube video, he mentioned that global admin right is needed to register an App for embedding powerBI report to custom web application via REST APIs.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=egP0GHSOUIM&t=221s.

I tried to use the provided URL: https://dev.powerbi.com/apps, I found I can register a web app, and I can get client id and client secret.

But when I check the permission for powerbi in azure portal, I found at the top right, there is check box for application permissions not checked, also it says it requires admin. Do I really need to have global admin to make the integration work?

Thanks,
Jack

Answer (score 0):

I guess global admin is not required,I made it work with C# sample codes.